# How to get Laravel Collection from images using views

Tags: mysql, laravel, collections

I have two tables `images` and `views`.  images: `user_id`, `name`, `path`.  views: `user_id`, `viewable_id`, `viewabe_type`, `count`.  Image has Polmophic relation through `viewable_id`.  How do i extract Laravel Collection of Images that have view count over 100?

Comment: So, you want us to write a query for you? Are you using Eloquent? What do your models look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am learning Laravel and thought I'd learn from the experienced other than pages and pages of Google search. Image belongs to User, Viewables is Polymophic to Image and User e.g. `user_id`, `viewable_id`, `viewable_type`, `count` => `2`, `31`, `App\Image`, `9` ... How would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $data= DB::table('images')
        ->join('views', 'images.user_id', '=', 'views.user_id')
        ->select('images.user_id', 'images.path', 'views.count')
        ->where('views.count', '>', 100);
        ->orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: thank you,  how then do I tackle getting latest view counts e.g Image 52 -> 100 views, Image 30 -> 98 views, Image 109 -> 90 views. This $data gives latest Image first e.g Image 30 -> 98 views, Image 52 -> 100 views, Image 109 -> 90 views.